# Android Maps API2 release version working locally but not through Alpha test

Tags: android, api, dictionary, release

I'm now doing alpha test of my app through Play store. The problem is that while the map works perfectly when I install using Android Studio, it's just blank if installed through Play Store.
I use exactly the key signing my apk for my API key in the google API console. In fact I deleted the debug api key to avoid potential problem.
I also find that while my apk uploaded is about 2.4 mb, the apk downloading from Google Play is 2 mb.
I read the question here [Android Maps API2 release key working locally but not through Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639398/android-maps-api2-release-key-working-locally-but-not-through-play-store) , but the reason is still mysterious. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that Google Play Store replace my certificate with its autogenerated one. It works perfectly after I added this key to the api console :)